# select instance where instance OR associations match fuzzy text

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

This is hard to explain, so I'll start with what I've got.

User has_many Dependents
Users and Dependents have names.
I want a scope on User that will return all of the users whose names, OR whose dependents names match a certain fuzzy text.

It seems to not return all of the expected results. This is my current scope:

```
scope :by_fuzzy_text, lambda { |text|
  text = "%#{text}%"
  joins(:dependents).where('name ILIKE ? OR dependents.name ILIKE ?', text, text).uniq
}
```

The issue is that it's returning unexpected results. It seems to only work on the first 11 Users in my database, despite there being over 100. So no matter how perfectly the scope matches, it will only return the results who are one of the first 11 users in the database. I do NOT have this issue if I'm not using Joins.

Hopefully that makes sense. The uniq on the end is because if the user has multiple dependents, the user is returned multiple times, once for each dependent.

Example:

```
User1 = "Sam Smith"
-Dependent1.1 = "Ralph Smith"
-Dependent1.2 = "Alex Smith"

User2 = "April Shower"
-Dependent2.1 = "Zach Shower"
-Dependen2.2 = "Sally Smith"
```

`User.by_fuzzy_text('w') => [User2]`

(April Sho**w**er, Zach Sho**w**er)

`User.by_fuzzy_text('z') => [User2]`

(**Z**ach Shower)

`User.by_fuzzy_text('x') => [User1]`

(Ale**x** Smith)

`User.by_fuzzy_text('smith') => [User1, User2]`

(Sam **Smith**, Ralph **Smith**, Alex **Smith**, Sally **Smith**)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do a LEFT OUTER JOINS to include the Users who did not have any dependents.

```
joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN dependents ON users.id = dependents.user_id').where('name ILIKE ? OR name ILIKE ?', text, text).uniq`
```